# Download Xcode 10.2.1 in macOS High Sierra (10.13.6)

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mojave, xcode, mac-appstore

I use MacBook pro with macOS High Sierra (10.13.6). The version of Xcode am using is 10.1 and I see the updated Xcode in AppStore is 10.3 which is not compatible with my environment since it expects macOS Mojave 10.14.6.

How can I get Xcode 10.2.1 which got released after Xcode 10.1 release. Also will  MacBook pro with macOS High Sierra (10.13.6) get macOS Mojave 10.14.6 update ? Thanks

Comment: I've closed this question as a duplicate because of the 'Xcode' question. As for the other question, we don't generally allow two questions in a single post, and in this case your 2nd question is really a separate distinct question. To answer *that* question we really need to know the hardware specs of your MacBook Pro (or, more specifically, the model) in order to answer the question. Feel free to post another question about that if you're still looking for an answer.